# Fundamental group of one of the covering spaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$ from Hatcher's book

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

I have a question about the fundamental group of the covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$ from part (6) of the following table from Hatcher's book [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFjyI.jpg)

Hatcher claims that all the fundamental groups from the table can be computed using Van Kampen's theorem, but thinking a few hours about the space from
(6), I still can not find the right covering to compute the fundamental group using Van Kampen's theorem. Any hint/solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: One is not restricted to a single application of Van Kampen's Theorem. Applying it multiple times is a perfectly valid method.